# What does this doubly generic return type (public <T> TypedQuery<T>) indicate?

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, jpa-2.0

JPA and Hibernate have some methods with some genericized return types that I don't understand, e.g.,

```
public <T> TypedQuery<T> createNamedQuery(String name, Class<T> resultClass)
```

in [AbstractEntityManagerImpl](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.6.3.Final/org/hibernate/ejb/AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java/?v=source).  I would have expected a return type of `TypedQuery<T>`.  What does the `<T>` that precedes the `TypedQuery<T>` indicate?

This isn't a purely theoretical question on my part.  I have some code that is giving me compilation errors.

```
    TypedQuery<LogEntity> query =
            entityManager.createNamedQuery(
                    "LogEntity.findByContentionText",
                    LogEntity.class);
```

The error reads:

```
method createNamedQuery in interface javax.persistence.EntityManager cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String
  found: java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<mypackage.LogEntity>
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

This is somewhat misleading, because `EntityManager.createNamedQuery` is overloaded with:

```
public Query createNamedQuery(String name);
```

and

```
public <T> TypedQuery<T> createNamedQuery(String name, Class<T> resultClass);
```

The error refers to the first definition, whereas I am trying to match the second definition.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter type of a generic class/method must be declared at some point. For a generic class, you declare it in the class definition:

```
class X<T> {}
```

On the other hand, for a generic method within a class that is **not** generic, you have to declare it in the method declaration itself:

```
class NotGeneric{
  public <T> X<T> genericMethod(String s, Class<T> cls){}
}
```

Finally, your error is probably due to a different issue, e.g., you might have jar files for  `javax.persistence` 1.x *or* both 1.x *and* 2.0 at the same time in your classpath. The overloaded method [was added in 2.0](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29).

Comment: It does look like we have several versions of JPA in our humongous, convoluted classpath.  Now, I just have to figure out how to simplify this mess.  Any ideas?  ;)

Comment: what dependency/build tool are you using?

Comment: We're using maven.  It is showing a classpath of nearly 300 entries, of which 4 jars have "jpa" in the name.  At first glance, it looks like JPA 2.0 should be the one that wins, but I'd better take a second glance.

Comment: jpa in the name does not mean they conflict. I haven't used Maven in a while. Try [expanding the dep tree to fix conflicts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html).

Answer (score 2):

The return type is `TypedQuery<T>`. The `<T>` before the return type means that the method is a generic method, having a single generic type called `T`.

It thus means that the caller of the method decides the type of the returned TypedQuery, by passing a Class instance. If you pass Foo.class as argument, the method will return a `TypedQuery<Foo>`.

Other generic methods don't take a generic type as argument, and the caller can decide which type to use by using, for example

```
Collections.<Foo>emptyList();
```

Your code doesn't compile because you have an old version of JPA in your classpath, where the method `createNamedQuery(String, Class)` doesn't exist (see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html for the documentation of this old version).